# Perl: Extract element from XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl

How would I extract a single element from an XML document using XML::Twig?

**XML Code:**

```
<report>
    <reportheader>
        <month>February 2015</month>
    </reportheader>
</report>
```

**What I've tried**

```
XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '/report/reportheader/month' => sub {
            printf qq|%s\n|, $_;
        },
    },  
)->parsefile($ARGV[0]);
```

But this just outputs `XML::Twig::Elt=HASH(0x343af70)`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the anonymous subrutine, `$_` is the element object. If you want to print the text of the element use:

```
printf qq|%s\n|, $_->text_only;
```

That yields:

```
February 2015
```

Or if you want to print the whole element, use instead:

```
printf qq|%s\n|, $_->outer_xml;
```

That yields:

```
<month>February 2015</month>
```

And you can look at the docs, they are pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is tempting to use the callback system of `XML::Twig`, it is often more simple to simply parse the entire XML data into an 'XML::Twig' data structure and access the contents of that using `findnodes` etc.

Here's an example that prints the text content of all elements that match the XPath expression `/report/reportheader/month`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;     # For `say`

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile(shift @ARGV);

for my $report_month ( $twig->findnodes('/report/reportheader/month') ) {
  say $report_month->trimmed_text;
}
```

**output**

```
February 2015
```

Comment: Agreed. Callbacks are great for extract-and-purge type operations, but can quickly become messy and confusing to no real benefit otherwise.