# Perl: Receive multiple children of XPath element

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-twig

I am using XML::Twig to parse an XML file and print some info. Here is my XML File:

```
<report>
    <reportheader>
        <month>February 2015</month>
        <dateofgeneration>20/02/2015 - 12:29:02</dateofgeneration>
    </reportheader>
</report>
```

and I have the following code:

```
XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '/report/reportheader' => sub {
            printf qq|%s\n|, $_->text;
        },
    },  
)->parsefile($ARGV[0]);
```

Unfortunately this prints `February 201520/02/2015 - 12:29:02`. Is there a way to separate these two instead of having them concatenate? I was hoping to do something like:

```
printf qq|Month: %s\nDate: %s\n|, $_->text[0], $_->text[1];
```

to separate it into the two variables but that did not work.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `'/report/reportheader/*'` for the selector? The 'text' or 'value' of an Element node is generally the concatenation of text-content from itself and all children.

Comment: Your modification worked slightly. It now prints them on separate lines but I want to have different text preceding them, i.e. `Month: February 2015\nDate: 20/02/2015....`

Comment: You should be able to check the name of the current node. Or you could create a handler for each node.

Comment: How would I create a handler for each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I intended to write an answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28866886) that showed how it may be simpler to avoid the callback system of `XML::Twig` altogether for anything other than huge XML data files. I have added [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884892/622310) now, and you might like to take a look.

The same approach is fine for this problem as well. It is simply a matter of finding all `/report/reportheader` elements, and printing the text content of their (first) `month` and `dateofgeneration` child elements.

Here's a working example. Note that it assumes that the two child elements will *always* exist. If that isn't true of your actual data then you may need to test for their existence first, but note that `first_child_trimmed_text` (and its brethren) will just return an empty string without complaint if the specified node doesn't exist.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;     # For `say`

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile(shift @ARGV);

for my $report_header ( $twig->findnodes('/report/reportheader') ) {
  say $report_header->first_child_trimmed_text('month');
  say $report_header->first_child_trimmed_text('dateofgeneration');
}
```

**output**

```
February 2015
20/02/2015 - 12:29:02
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like this more than what I currently had. Quick question to avoid asking another question. Is it possible to use findnodes to search for all nodes of "month" and store them in array?

Comment: @Bijan: Sure. You would write `my @months = $twig->findnodes('//month')` to find all `month` elements anywhere in an XML document. It sounds like you could use an [XPath tutorial](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html), but please avoid W3Schools, which is primarily a money-making exercise rather than a source of information with integrity. Best of all is [the RFC itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: Is there a one-liner to just load the text from the results? `my @months = $twig->findnodes('//month')->text()` gives me "Cant located object method text" I would rather not have to use a foreach to load `$_->text()`

Comment: @Bijan: You can't do that because `findnodes` in scalar context just returns a count of the number of elements found. (You have also shown only half of the error message. Please don't do that.) You would need to use `map` if you *really* want it in one line, like this `my @months = map $_->trimmed_text, $twig->findnodes('//month')` but it is strange to require a single-statement solution when they are often less clear than the equivalent iteration.

Comment: One last thing (I promise). What is best way to pull a single element like '/report/reportheader/month' instead of using a for loop

Comment: @Bijan: `/report/reportheader/month` may match many elements; but to snag just the first one you can write `my ($first_report_month) = $twig->findnodes('/report/reportheader/month')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72360/discussion-between-bijan-and-borodin).

Comment: @Bijan: No, I'm sorry I fell for the ***"Quick question to avoid asking another question"***. Stack Overflow isn't a forum where you get your problems fixed personally: it is meant to become a repository of common programming problems and their solutions. The *primary purpose* of questions here is to help others who may have a similar problem. Anything too specific is off-topic, and asking questions in comments hides that information from other people who may be searching for it. Please be a little more public-spirited and ask a new question if you can't find it answered on this site already.